# Impedindo que entradas sejam excluídas utilizando Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Tem alguma maneira de eu setar que determinada entrada de uma tabela no banco não seja excluida?

Por exemplo, eu criei uma table `usuários` no banco através da classe `User` utilizando as **anotations do Hibernate e JPA** e gostaria que o Usuário Administrador não pudesse ser excluido.

Comment: Colocando direto no banco o cadastro de um administrador principal, você poderia não fornecer a opção de exclusão, conferindo no banco e retornando um erro se for o Administrador. Não sei se existe algo próprio do Hibernate/JPA pra isso.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que esse controle de acesso de um determinado usuário seja por meio banco em que você está utilizando, por exemplo no MYSQL:

[image: Gerenciamento de Acesso ao Banco de Dados]

Gerenciamento de Acesso ao Banco de Dados
Ou então colocar alguma condição na sua aplicação de que quando o usuário Usuário Administrador estiver usando sua aplicação não seja possível executar o código SQL de remoção do registro, exemplo:

Verificação na remoção de registro de uma tabela:

[image: Verificação na remoção de registro de uma tabela]

Comment: Como assim? Esta sugerindo que o usuario execute um `drop table`!?

Comment: @Wakim to sugerindo pra não executar só olhar a condição... se o usuarioLogado for "Usuário Administrador" não execute o drop table.

Comment: Sim, mas não se exclui um registro com `drop table` (isso vai apagar a tabela) e sim com um `delete`, mas ele provavelmente já usa o `delete` do JPA para isso.

Comment: "Determinada entrada de uma tabela no banco não seja excluida"